# Setting up MySQL database for stand-alone Spring Boot application to be used in another device

Tags: mysql, database, spring, spring-boot, production-environment

I'm developing an application using:

- Spring boot
- MySQL

I'm new to these, and my question is how I can run my application in another device. I'm asking about:

- If I set up a MySQL on localhost, how can I take it to another device, so that the built jar file works perfectly fine with it?
- I'm looking for a solution like, establishing connection with a locally saved database file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your database on a network... then only you can access it from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

If you want the application to use a local database, you should look at the inmemory databases like H2, HSQLDB or Derby. You can not install Mysql in all devices.